# Do we need any program updates to migrate our bots from Bot Framework to Azure?

Tags: azure, botframework, skype-for-business

Recently, MS announced that they will migrate all bots to the new Azure Bot Service by 3/31/2018.

We have a chat bot service that communicates via Skype for Business channel.

Do we need any program updates at our end to migrate our bots to Azure?
Or do we just need to do manual migration steps and don't need program updates?

Answer (score 0):

There will be no updates to your code needed. The migration will move your bot from the "preview" Web app or function and deploy it into the new type of Web App or Function App available after release.  Your source code will be moved as well and should remain untouched and fully functioning as it was prior to migration.  Your endpoint in your bot settings will also automatically be updated to reflect the new endpoint from the new Web App or Function App created.

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot).